# Is there a list of sponsored tags?

Tags: support, sponsored-tags

Is there a list of sponsored tags?

Comment: It's [on the to-do list](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/sponsored-tags/info).

Comment: @jonrsharpe the post linked to by the tag wiki is 6-8 *years* old ...

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is your interest in seeing a list of sponsored tags?

Comment: Out of curiosity :)

Comment: Lol. As the "to-do list" promise was made in 2009 and the person making that promise hasn't been seen for more than a decade I think it is probably time to remove that from the Wiki

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Until this gets implemented or be available on either SEDE or the StackAPI, this is the list of sponsored tags as of today. At the end of the list you find the userscript to create this list.

[admob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/admob)
[amazon-rds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-rds)
[android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android)
[android-ndk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-ndk)
[android-pay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-pay)
[android-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-studio)
[android-tv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-tv)
[appcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/appcode)
[azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure)
[clion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clion)
[couchbase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/couchbase)
[couchbase-bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/couchbase-bucket)
[couchbase-java-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/couchbase-java-api)
[couchbase-lite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/couchbase-lite)
[couchbase-nodejs-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/couchbase-nodejs-sdk)
[couchbase-sync-gateway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/couchbase-sync-gateway)
[couchbase-view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/couchbase-view)
[dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dart)
[eddystone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eddystone)
[elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/elasticsearch)
[ews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ews)
[ews-managed-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ews-managed-api)
[exchange-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exchange-server)
[exchangewebservices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exchangewebservices)
[gae-datastore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gae-datastore)
[gcloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gcloud)
[gcloud-node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gcloud-node)
[gcloud-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gcloud-python)
[github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/github)
[gmail-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gmail-api)
[go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/go)
[go-couchbase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/go-couchbase)
[google-analytics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-analytics)
[google-analytics-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-analytics-api)
[google-api-cpp-client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-api-cpp-client)
[google-api-dotnet-client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-api-dotnet-client)
[google-api-java-client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-api-java-client)
[google-api-js-client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-api-js-client)
[google-api-nodejs-client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-api-nodejs-client)
[google-api-objc-client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-api-objc-client)
[google-api-php-client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-api-php-client)
[google-api-python-client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-api-python-client)
[google-api-ruby-client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-api-ruby-client)
[google-app-engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-app-engine)
[google-apps-marketplace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-marketplace)
[google-apps-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script)
[google-beacon-platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-beacon-platform)
[google-bigquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-bigquery)
[google-cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-cast)
[google-chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-chrome)
[google-chrome-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-chrome-app)
[google-chrome-arc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-chrome-arc)
[google-chrome-devtools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-chrome-devtools)
[google-chrome-extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-chrome-extension)
[google-classroom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-classroom)
[google-cloud-bigtable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-cloud-bigtable)
[google-cloud-dataflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-cloud-dataflow)
[google-cloud-datalab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-cloud-datalab)
[google-cloud-dataproc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-cloud-dataproc)
[google-cloud-datastore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-cloud-datastore)
[google-cloud-dns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-cloud-dns)
[google-cloud-endpoints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-cloud-endpoints)
[google-cloud-messaging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-cloud-messaging)
[google-cloud-platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-cloud-platform)
[google-cloud-pubsub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-cloud-pubsub)
[google-cloud-sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-cloud-sql)
[google-cloud-storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-cloud-storage)
[google-cloud-trace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-cloud-trace)
[google-compute-engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-compute-engine)
[google-container-engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-container-engine)
[google-custom-search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-custom-search)
[google-drive-android-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-drive-android-api)
[google-drive-realtime-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-drive-realtime-api)
[google-drive-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-drive-sdk)
[google-earth-plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-earth-plugin)
[google-fit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-fit)
[google-fusion-tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-fusion-tables)
[google-gdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-gdk)
[google-geocoding-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-geocoding-api)
[google-glass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-glass)
[google-hadoop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-hadoop)
[google-latitude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-latitude)
[google-maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-maps)
[google-maps-android-api-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-maps-android-api-2)
[google-maps-api-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-maps-api-3)
[google-mirror-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-mirror-api)
[google-nativeclient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-nativeclient)
[google-oauth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-oauth)
[google-openid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-openid)
[google-places-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-places-api)
[google-play](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-play)
[google-play-games](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-play-games)
[google-play-services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-play-services)
[google-plus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-plus)
[google-prediction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-prediction)
[google-search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-search)
[google-search-appliance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-search-appliance)
[google-static-maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-static-maps)
[google-tag-manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-tag-manager)
[google-translate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-translate)
[google-tv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-tv)
[google-wallet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-wallet)
[intellij-idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intellij-idea)
[jetty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jetty)
[kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kotlin)
[kubernetes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kubernetes)
[libcouchbase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/libcouchbase)
[mod-pagespeed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mod-pagespeed)
[ms-office](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-office)
[nest-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nest-api)
[office-2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/office-2013)
[office365](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/office365)
[onenote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/onenote)
[paypal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/paypal)
[paypal-adaptive-payments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/paypal-adaptive-payments)
[paypal-ipn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/paypal-ipn)
[paypal-sandbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/paypal-sandbox)
[paypal-subscriptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/paypal-subscriptions)
[phpstorm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phpstorm)
[pycharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pycharm)
[realm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/realm)
[resharper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/resharper)
[rubymine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rubymine)
[solace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/solace)
[solace-mq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/solace-mq)
[sony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sony)
[sony-camera-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sony-camera-api)
[sony-lifelog-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sony-lifelog-api)
[sony-smarteyeglass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sony-smarteyeglass)
[sony-smartwatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sony-smartwatch)
[sony-xperia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sony-xperia)
[stormpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stormpath)
[upsource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/upsource)
[webstorm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webstorm)
[youtrack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/youtrack)
[youtube-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/youtube-api)

You can let the following userscript hammer for over an hour on the [/tags](https://stackoverflow.com/tags) page and grab the final result from the Developer Console of your browser. This is tested in Chrome with Tamper Monkey.

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         sponsered tags
// @namespace    https://stackoverflow.com/users/578411/rene
// @version      0.1
// @description  list sponsered tags
// @author       rene
// @match        *://stackoverflow.com/tags*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';

    var page = 1,
        timer;

    timer = setInterval(function () {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            var doc,
                links,
                a,
                i;
            if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
                if (xhr.status === 200) {
                    page++;
                    if (page > 1714) {
                        clearInterval(timer);    
                    }
                    doc = xhr.response;
                    // all tags have a link with a specific class name
                    links = doc.getElementsByClassName('post-tag');
                    for(var i=0; i < links.length; i = i +1) {
                        a = links[i];
                        // if those links have an image tag, they are sponsered
                        if (a.children.length > 0) {
                            console.log('[tag:' + a.textContent + ']');
                        }
                    }

                } else {
                    console.log(xhr.status);
                    clearInterval(timer);
                }
            }

        };
        xhr.responseType = 'document';
        xhr.open('GET','https://stackoverflow.com/tags?tab=name&page=' + page);
        xhr.send(null);
    }, 2500);


})();
```

Comment: `page > 1346` needs manual adjustment ... because I'm lazy ...

Comment: The list is outdated, also the script doesn't work anymore (from the console on chrome) I have no results and if I try to run it multiple times, I got "Too many requests" and I can't acces stackoverflow for a few minutes.

Comment: @MickaelB. it still works for me if I open it on "https://stackoverflow.com/tags" but as it sorts on name it might take some time before you find Facebook. I've increased the timeout to 2500 (2,5 seconds per page) so it is less likely to put you in an IP ban but reloading it several times might still trip it. Keep in mind this has to run for at least 1714 X 2,5 seconds to find you all tags. The scripts stays silent in general, but does spit out an message if in its readystate it hits something that is not a success code of 200. I've tested this in Chrome with TamperMonkey.