# adzerk.net causes mixed content error on main site

Tags: bug, status-planned, advertising, ssl

It looks like there is an asset loaded from stackoverflow.com that is breaking the HTTPS configuration, causing the site to be flagged with the mixed content warning (hence downgraded to insecure).

The culprit is probably a banner, loaded from `http://engine.adzerk.net/` (notice the `http:` and not `https:`).

[image: Mixed content error]

Comment: Pretty sure the answer is going to end up being "SSL is not fully supported yet".  [https://www.stackoverflow.com redirects to insecure http://stackoverflow.com](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270602/https-www-stackoverflow-com-redirects-to-insecure-http-stackoverflow-com)

Comment: this is probably caused by a specific ad. Can you identify which one it is?

Comment: @rene it's the entire sponsored links block at the top of the tag https://cl.ly/1H3k2N1x3u0b/Screen%20Shot%202016-09-02%20at%2014.35.37.png

Comment: Yeah, rerpro-ed when visiting the [android Tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) as well. Looks all [sponsered tags](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328236/is-there-a-list-of-sponsored-tags/328278#328278) have this issue.

Answer (score 21):

**We're on it!**
We see those issues as well, and we're working with our ad server to get this addressed. It will take time, and it will only apply to new tag sponsorships in the future. Updating *every* tag sponsorship on the site would take an incredible amount of effort. Some of the larger tags ([android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android), for example) will be taken care of, though.

I'll post an update here when we have one.

Thank you for bringing this to my attention!

---

Status update: our ad server won't be able to automate this for us, so we're looking into other ways to get this done.