# Blazor tag has incorrect icon

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, advertising, sponsored-tags

The [blazor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/blazor) tag which is for [blazor](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/aspnet/web-apps/blazor) has an incorrect icon.

[image]

The correct icon for Blazor is

[image]

I feel that we have been though this previously ([here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/393853/1841839)), that someone shouldn't be able to pay for an icon on a badge they don't own the copyright for.

Comment: ___Again___? How does this keep happening?

Comment: @Cerbrus this is what you get when you give Marketing toys to play with ...

Comment: A reverse image search gives me an Eminem video that isn't suitable for all audiences :/

Comment: I mean, out of the the last 15 posts in [meta-tag:sponsored-tags], 8 are the same "wrong icon" issue...

Comment: I wounder if we can use the SO api to check for images on tags then use @rene reverse image search to spot the wrong icons.

Comment: @DaImTo last time I checked there was no API nor SEDE so I produced this awesomeness: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/328278/578411

Comment: @rene defiantly qualify that as awesomeness.

Comment: It isn't wrong, full size image [is here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TelerikInc.TelerikBlazorVSExtensions).  No real need to protect fools with more money than common sense btw.

Comment: So Telerik UI has sponsored the Blazor tag as a way to get advertisement for their product.  interesting.

Comment: If that's what happened (Telerik sponsored Blazor and put their own icon on the tag), it sounds like a process change is sorely needed. That is misleading.

Comment: If this is not just another of the (far too many) "oopsies, wrong tag" goofs and is in fact intentionally requested by Telerik, then this would normally be textbook trademark infringement by using the Blazor logo as part of their own, more complex logo, and then inserting said logo on a 'blazor' tag; they are essentially associating someone else's product and reputation with their own name. Because blazor and .NET are open-source, I'm not sure if the logo is trademarked, so worst case Telerik may just be guilty of bottom-of-the-barrel behavior here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks for pointing it out, and sorry for the delay in reply here. We've removed the logo.

*Disclaimer: I'm an employee of Stack, working as a Product Manager in the Advertising team*

Comment: Hi, thanks for fixing this! I have a question, though: This kind of issue has happened several times before. Is there something in the process of adding / changing those icons that's not going as it should? Can this be prevented in the future?

Comment: @Cerbrus - yeah good point. I've had some time to think about it. TL;DR about my thoughts is that (in our current situation) the only feasible way is mainly through improving the process. Automatic checks on these things are too complex. In the upcoming period, we'll be adding some notifications (in our internal systems) that should prevent people from adding these. I'll also re-iterate the awareness among my colleagues regarding this policy.

Comment: Awesome! Let's hope that's the end of this kind of issue :D